# Bypass https by NGINX as proxy server

Tags: nginx

I used nginx as regular proxy server. However, it only works with http but not https. It returns an error page for the https requests.Is there a way to configure NGINX for it to bypass https?

```
worker_processes auto;
events {
  worker_connections 1024;
}


http {
  include mime.types;
  default_type application/octet-stream;
  sendfile on;
  keepalive_timeout 65;

  server {
     resolver 114.114.114.114;
     listen 8228;
     server_name localhost;
     location / {
       proxy_pass $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_buffers 256 4k;
     }

  error_page 500 502 503 504 /50x.html;
  location = /50x.html {
     root html;
  }
  }
```

Comment: Are you making a reverse proxy?  A regular proxy server?  And what's with this redirecting?  Just google.com, or everything?

Comment: I just have nginx as a regular proxy server. it redirect everything the user requests and return the response.

Comment: Post whole config to pastebin please. Is it catches requests on 443 port?

Comment: @Dmitry Verkhoturov thanks, I pasted the whole config.

Comment: You have to listen on 443 and also set up the ssl stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to add new `server` location with https-related settings, this might do the job:

```
server {
   resolver 114.114.114.114;

   // note the port is changed, you can't serve HTTP and HTTPS on same port
   listen 8229 ssl;

   // here you must place valid certificates (may be self-singed)
   // startssl example:
   // # (cat example.com.pem & wget -O - https://www.startssl.com/certs/class1/sha2/pem/sub.class1.server.sha2.ca.pem) | tee -a /etc/nginx/ssl/domain.pem > /dev/null
   ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/domain.pem;

   // private key decoded, example
   // # openssl rsa -in decoded.key -out domain.key
   ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/domain.key;

   server_name localhost;

   location / {
       proxy_pass $scheme://$http_host$request_uri;
       proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
       proxy_buffers 256 4k;
   }
```

There are lots of optional parameters for HTTPS configuration you must use on production for sufficient security, I've already described [really good security configuration](https://gist.github.com/paskal/628882bee1948ef126dd) on github gist by link, also [official documentation on ssl module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_ssl_module.html) is a good point for start.