# Getting 404 errors with WordPress permalinks enabled, running Nginx

Tags: wordpress, nginx

I'm having some issues getting my WordPress blog to work with Nginx, any advice would be great, I'm getting 404 errors in any place except the home page which loads fine, any advice?

I have included my conf file here...

```
server {
    server_name mydomain.com www.mydomain.com;
    listen 11.11.11.11;
    root /home/mydomain/public_html;
    index index.html index.htm index.php;
    access_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_access_log;
    error_log /var/log/virtualmin/mydomain.com_error_log;
    fastcgi_param GATEWAY_INTERFACE CGI/1.1;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_SOFTWARE nginx;
    fastcgi_param QUERY_STRING $query_string;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_METHOD $request_method;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_TYPE $content_type;
    fastcgi_param CONTENT_LENGTH $content_length;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME /home/mydomain/public_html$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME $fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_param REQUEST_URI $request_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
    fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT /home/mydomain/public_html;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_ADDR $remote_addr;
    fastcgi_param REMOTE_PORT $remote_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
    fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
    location ~ \.php$ {
        try_files $uri =404;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/php-nginx/142618852813437.sock/socket;
    }
    listen 11.11.11.11:443 default ssl;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing one important directive there:

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args; 
}
```

By the way, ssl won't work in this configuration, you need more directives as described [there](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28904831/bypass-https-by-nginx-as-proxy-server/29063991#29063991).